# Swapping two characters in a word with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to think of the function I would use to grab a character *x* amount of spaces from the left or right side of a string.

Let's say a cell has the word **superuser** in it. I need a formula in another cell that will swap two characters, given an amount of spaces from the start and end of the word.

So if I say 2, it will grab **u** (second from start) and **e** (second from last) and swap them, giving you **seperusur** as your new word.

I think I'd use =REPLACE to start it off but I'm not sure what to use inside of it to get the 2nd character from the start & end of the text string.

Comment: You're looking for `substitute` `left` and `right` but there's no formula I can think of that will store the first original character in memory to use it for the second replacement; as soon as you replace the first one, a function will reference the replacement rather than the original. I think you'd need a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `FIND()` and `SEARCH()` functions to store the locations, and then swap them once you know the locations.

Comment: Can you provide a formula to achieve it with those functions?

Comment: =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(C14,FIND("-",C14),1,"+"),FIND("-",C14,FIND("-",C14)+1),1,"+"),FIND("+",C14),1,"-"),FIND("+",C14,FIND("+",C14)+1),1,"-")

Comment: where + and - are the two strings you want to swap and where C14 is the original string

Comment: +1 for a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Can use:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(C2,C3-1)&MID(C2,LEN(C2)-C3+1,1)&MID(C2,C3+1,LEN(C2)-C3*2)&MID(C2,C3,1)&RIGHT(C2,C3-1),"")`

*When C2 = string & C3 = first and last positions to switch (a #)